# Find first occurrence of two characters

Tags: java, string

So I have dealt with this problem before and thought there would be an accepted pattern to solve the problem, but I have yet to find anything. I tried searching around and I have tried tinkering around myself and neither resulted in any satisfactory answers so I am turning to SO

```
String str = "blah1blah2"
```

I want to know whether the char '1' or '2' occurs first (this is just a made up example obviously). I know I could use str.indexOf() for 1 and 2 to compare, but this presents the problem of it possibly returning -1.

Let me know what would be a good way to tackle this.

FYI: I am working in Java but I think this sort of indexOf function is pretty common in other languages.

Comment: Why is `indexOf()` returning -1 a problem?

Comment: So will you always be testing specifically with 2 characters?

Comment: Could you give an example (trace) what the expected results would be if you had this imaginary function in Java?

Comment: @DougRamsey because if I am looking for the first of the two characters to appear, then the -1 is going to be less then anywhere in the string. Ex: If '1' is at pos 5 and '2' is not in the string, I want to get 5 as the index, not -1. However, a simple compare would give me a -1.

Comment: @hbtest: `if (returnedValue == -1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what degree of flexibility you require, but I would just do this the good-old-fashioned way of looping through the `String`, something like this:

```
public static char findFirstChar(String str, char c1, char c2) {
    for (char c : str.toCharArray())
        if (c == c1 || c == c2)
            return c;
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, this will return the `char` it encounters first or 0 if neither neither `char`s are found in the string.

If you want to search for an arbitrary number of character:

```
public static char findFirstChar(String str, char ... chars) {
    for (char c1 : str.toCharArray())
        for (char c2 : chars)
            if (c1 == c2)
                return c1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid looping through it, but this was the only answer that didn't have 3 if statements with easy to mess up logic

Answer (score 1):

I would say you should start by defining exactly what behavior you want.  Assume your search terms are "1" and "2", what should be returned for each of the following strings?

- "blah1blah2"
- "blah2blah1"
- "blahblah1"
- "blahblah2"
- "blahblah"

Write test cases for each of these, with your answer.  Now make the tests pass.  Simple!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's another way but to check whether the characters are there before you compare:

```
String result;
if (str.indexOf('1') > -1 && str.indexOf('2') > -1 ) {
   str.indexOf('2') > str.indexOf('1') ? result ="1 before 2":result="2 before 1";
}
else {
    result="one of them is not there"
}
System.out.println(result);
```

All depends on the results you expect

Comment: But I still need to know which one is present, because then it is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "blah1blah2"
int indexOf1 = str.indexOf(1);
int indexOf2 = str.indexOf(2);

if(indexOf1!=-1)
{
    if(indexOf2!=-1)
    {

    int flag = indexOf1 - indexOf2;

    if(flag<0) // 1 first
    else // 2 first

    }

    else 
        {  // 1 is present, but 2 is not }
}

else
 {
     if(indexOf2!=-1) // 2 is present, but 1 is not
 }
```

Comment: But I still need to know which one is present, because then it is what I am looking for.